# Determining a set number of days between continuous datetime records each year conditionally on ID

Tags: r, time-series

I have a large data set of records that reflects specific detections of PIT tagged fish by antennas over many years. Here is a [link](https://github.com/CatMcAdams/TagData) to the data, though I will try and explain best I can.

Each individual fish id is determined by MostRecentTag which has a corresponding location and DateTime associated with the detection. Fish can be detected multiple times as much as each second, resulting in generally many records per fish. The data is over a few years, 2016 to present, with my interest lying really in detections at RiverName Green River Canal between 2016-2018. It is possible for a fish to stick around an antenna for a long time, get detected many days in a row, then disappear and come back some time later.

My goal is to determine, within each year, if and how many times a fish has a 30 day gap in detection at the Green River Canal. Antennas aren't perfect and may miss fish so if a gap of detection is less than that, for my purposes, I'm going to assume it never left the area. so if a fish is detected 29 days after its previous detection at the Green River Canal, the 30-day gap count should start over from that date.

It's one thing to look for clusters of dates, but I'm struggling with extending a cluster if detection occurs within that 30-day window. Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Apologies if I'm missing helpful info- I'm new to this. Happy to provide more info.

I want my output to look like:

| MostRecentTag | year | TimesRevisited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3D91C2C53C669 | 2016 | 0 |
| 3D91C2C53C772 | 2016 | 1 |
| 3D91C2C53C745 | 2017 | 0 |
| 3D91C2C53C767 | 2017 | 2 |
| 3D91C2C53C413 | 2018 | 0 |

Comment: Is this a programming question or a stats question? The last bit seems to imply that you are just interested in creating the bottom table to inspect the data.

Comment: Programming question-sorry for the confusion. I think I know what I need to do stats wise, but I can figure out how to format the data in the way I need.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to generate a new variable for each record that contains the "time to next seen"—then it's trivial to count the number of gaps > 30 days per fish. Note this approach attributes gaps to the year in which they **started**, which might not be your expectation. But this should be enough to get you going.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Load data
data <- read_csv("StackOverflowSubset.csv")

# Filter to include Green River Canal observations only
data <- data %>% filter(RiverName=="Green River Canal")

# Sort by tag and date time
data <- data %>% arrange(MostRecentTag,DateTime)

# Create variable TimeToNextEncounter - for each record,
# calculate time in days until next record (unless next
# record is from a different fish, then NA)
# Create Year variable for ease of manipulation
data <- data %>% mutate(
  TimeToNextEncounter =
    if_else(
      lead(MostRecentTag)==MostRecentTag,
      difftime(lead(DateTime),DateTime,units="days"),
      NA
    ),
  Year = year(EncounterDate)
)

# Table with all fish by year
all_fish_by_year <- data %>%
  group_by(MostRecentTag,Year) %>%
  summarise()

# Count of gaps >30 days for each fish by year
times_revisited <- data %>% 
  filter(TimeToNextEncounter>=30) %>%
  group_by(MostRecentTag,Year) %>%
  summarise(TimesRevisited = n(), .groups="keep")

# Join with all_fish_by_year to include those fish x year
# pairs where there were zero gaps >30 days
times_revisited <- times_revisited %>%
  left_join(x=all_fish_by_year,
            y=times_revisited,
            by=join_by(MostRecentTag,Year)) %>%
  mutate(TimesRevisited = if_else(
    is.na(TimesRevisited),0,TimesRevisited
  ))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you!!